# Android - multiple sounds

Tags: android

I'm confused as to how android handles sounds.

If music is playing, a sound interupts.
Is it possible for multiple apps to play music at once? So an ongoing sound.

And lets say 20 apps all need to sound a notification milliseconds apart. Does android play these at the time they come in simultaneously. Or does it queue them up?

Comment: What part of the question don't you understand? So lets say you have google play music and a third party music player. Are they both able to play their audio at the same time? Or does 1 get stopped as the other one starts.

Comment: And the second part of the question, lets say you had facebook and twitter that both get an update, it plays a notification sound right?. What happens if the both want to play a notification at the same time or milliseconds apart? Does it only play once or do they queue up and play one after the other?